# A lag when showing webview

Tags: android, android-layout, webview

I have an xml layout file like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:id="@+id/hdr_visimisi1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hdr_visimisi1"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/hdr_visimisi2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/hdr_visimisi1"
    android:text="@string/hdr_itjen"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/misi"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/hdr_visimisi2"
    android:background="@color/colorHeader"
    android:text="MISI INSPEKTORAT JENDERAL"
    android:textColor="@color/colorTextHeader"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/ct_misi"
    android:layout_below="@id/misi"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></WebView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/visi"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/ct_misi"
    android:background="@color/colorHeader"
    android:text="VISI INSPEKTORAT JENDERAL"
    android:textColor="@color/colorTextHeader"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/ct_visi"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/visi"></WebView>
```

When i run it in emulator, the textview part show directly, but the webview part comes after  the textview (may be 1-2 second lag).
Why it happened? And what can i do to minimize the lag time.

Comment: WebViews aren't the most performant Views... and they are also more complicate than simple TextViews - they can do a lot more.

Comment: @Andread : in my case there seems no lag for WebView. So that is basically the emulator problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to run your app on real device? 
Your problems probably come from your computer (low memory to run an emulator, maybe).

But here you can try to improve the performance by doing some thing like below:
Example:

```
mwebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
        WebSettings webSettings = mwebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        //improve webView performance
        mwebView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
        mwebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
        mwebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        mwebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);
        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webSettings.setSavePassword(true);
        webSettings.setSaveFormData(true);
        webSettings.setEnableSmoothTransition(true);
```

Full: https://github.com/TechCybo/Android-App-From-Responsive-Website-NavDrawer/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/mywebsite/mywebsite/MainActivity.java

Comment: `Your problems probably come from your computer (low memory to run an emulator, maybe)` real Android devices are usually **less performant** than your PC, even when hardly stressed.